# Dictionary<string, string> with child Dictionary

Tags: c#, facebook

Looking at https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435
I want to post the 'venue' information, How do I insert a child node / dictionary to postArgs? I can get the basic information posted as below

```
Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(GetAccessToken(code));

Dictionary<string, string> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postArgs["name"] = myEvent.Title;
postArgs["description"] = myEvent.Content;
postArgs["start_time"] = myEvent.DateStart;
postArgs["end_time"] = myEvent.DateEnd;
postArgs["location"] = myEvent.Location; //myEvent.City;//";
postArgs["page_id"] = "1234567";

//  Dictionary<string, string> postVenue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//  postVenue["city"] = myEvent.City;
//  postVenue["state"] = myEvent.County;
//  postVenue["country"] = "United Kingdom";
//  postVenue["latitude"] = myEvent.Latitude;
//  postVenue["longitude"] = myEvent.Longitude;

// here I need to add postVenue to postArgs as a child.

api.Post("/12345676788/events", postArgs);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

From your code I expect that the signature of Post is:

```
void Post(string, Dictionary<string,string>)
```

if that's the case then you'd need to serialize your dictionary (postVenue) and add the serialized string to the dictionary. The code accepting the post would then need to deserialize, however since you're calling a method on an API I suspect that you might not be able to supply the deserialization info to the called party.

Do you manage the code that will be using the posted arguments as well as the code posting the arguments?

the code for serialization could be :

```
var pairs = postVenue.Select(pair=>pair.Key + ":" + Pair.Value).ToArray();
var venues = string.Join(",",pairs);
```

you could then add it like so:

```
postArgs.Add("venues",venues);
```

and the deseialization would then be

```
var venues = postArgs["venues"]
var postVenue = (from pair in venues.Split(',')
                 select pair.Split(':')
                ).ToDictionary(pair => pair[0],pair=>pair[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't drop a dictionary within postArgs here, because you've declared it to have a value type of string.  The code

```
Dictionary<string, string> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>()
```

Indicates that it has keys of type string and values of type string.  If you wanted to be able to storea mixture of types, you'd want something like:

```
Dictionary<string, Object> postArgs = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
```

However, this would require you to cast values as they exited the dictionary.